# Keep empty lines and spaces with xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform a xml input adding/removing prefixes but I wanted to keep the xml without other modifications:

This is my method:

```
bool hc = false;
var usenamespaceprefix = true;
var Content = GetContent("f", "http://www.myschemedefinition.com/form", xmlcontent, usenamespaceprefix, out hc);

string GetContent(string prefix, string urins, string content, bool usenamespaceprefix, out bool hasChanged)
{
    var xslt = String.Empty;

    hasChanged = false;

    var newDocument = new XDocument();
    var result = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        var oldDocument = XDocument.Parse(content);
        switch (usenamespaceprefix)
        {
            case true:
                if (!content.Contains($"xmlns:{prefix}"))
                {
                    xslt = $@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                                <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
                                  <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>
                                  <xsl:preserve-space elements='*'/>
                                  <xsl:template match='*'>
                                    <xsl:element name='{prefix}:{{name()}}' xmlns:{prefix}='{urins}'>
                                      <xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()'/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                  </xsl:template>
                                  <xsl:template match='@*'>
                                    <xsl:attribute name='{{local-name(.)}}'>
                                      <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                  </xsl:template>
                                  <xsl:template match='comment()'>
                                     <xsl:copy />
                                  </xsl:template>
                                </xsl:stylesheet>";

                    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xslt))
                    {
                        using (XmlReader xsltReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
                        {
                            var transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
                            transformer.Load(xsltReader);
                            using (XmlReader oldDocumentReader = oldDocument.CreateReader())
                            {
                                using (var newDocumentWriter = newDocument.CreateWriter())
                                {
                                    transformer.Transform(oldDocumentReader, newDocumentWriter);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    result = newDocument.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    xslt = $@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>                                
                                <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
                                    xmlns:{prefix}=""{urins}"">
                                  <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>
                                  <xsl:preserve-space elements='*'/>
                                    <xsl:template match=""{prefix}:*"">
                                        <xsl:copy>
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select=""node()|@*""/>
                                        </xsl:copy>
                                    </xsl:template>
                                    <xsl:template match=""*"">
                                        <xsl:element name=""{prefix}:{{local-name()}}"">
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select=""node()|@*""/>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:template>
                                  <xsl:template match='@*'>
                                    <xsl:attribute name='{{local-name(.)}}'>
                                      <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                  </xsl:template>
                                  <xsl:template match='comment()'>
                                     <xsl:copy />
                                  </xsl:template>
                                </xsl:stylesheet>";

                    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xslt))
                    {
                        using (XmlReader xsltReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
                        {
                            var transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
                            transformer.Load(xsltReader);
                            using (XmlReader oldDocumentReader = oldDocument.CreateReader())
                            {
                                using (var newDocumentWriter = newDocument.CreateWriter())
                                {
                                    transformer.Transform(oldDocumentReader, newDocumentWriter);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    result = newDocument.ToString();
                }
                break;
            case false:
                xslt = $@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                                <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
                                  <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>
                                  <xsl:preserve-space elements='*'/>
                                  <xsl:template match='*'>
                                    <xsl:element name='{{local-name(.)}}' xmlns='{urins}'>
                                      <xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()'/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                  </xsl:template>
                                  <xsl:template match='@*'>
                                    <xsl:attribute name='{{local-name(.)}}'>
                                      <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                  </xsl:template>
                                  <xsl:template match='comment()'>
                                     <xsl:copy />
                                  </xsl:template>
                                </xsl:stylesheet>";
                using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xslt))
                {
                    using (XmlReader xsltReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
                    {
                        var transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
                        transformer.Load(xsltReader);
                        using (XmlReader oldDocumentReader = oldDocument.CreateReader())
                        {
                            using (var newDocumentWriter = newDocument.CreateWriter())
                            {
                                transformer.Transform(oldDocumentReader, newDocumentWriter);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            // Make sure the indentation is preserved
            var xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xmlSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            xmlSettings.Indent = true;
            xmlSettings.IndentChars = "\t";
            xmlSettings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, xmlSettings))
            {
                newDocument.Save(xmlWriter);
            }
            result = stringWriter.ToString();
        }

        // only for testing
        result = result.Replace("\"", "'").Trim();
        //content = content.Trim();

        hasChanged = content != result;

        return result;
    }
```

but it's doing some changes I don't want it to do:

- Add additional space at the end of the self-closed element: `<f:Cell Name='Option1Label'/>` to `<f:Cell Name='Option1Label' />` and also changing the indentation  of empty lines.
  [image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: In this case I would use text string processing and just do string replacement like "<prefix:" => "<". Any xslt processing may modify the formatting of the xml.

Comment: @PtitXav text processing is not an option without an overkill algorithm that identifies if  text is a comment or similar ...

Comment: I'm confused. You said you wanted to keep the XML without modifications, but you are deliberately asking for indentation to be added? I can't reconcile those two statements.

Comment: @MichaelKay If you check the screenshot you can see the output is almost identical, but I'm missing the indentation of empty line, which has 4 tabs and my output only 1. Without the last step using the xmlwriter my output doesn't have the same indentation as I'm receiving a tab based input.

Comment: The aim of an XML indenter is to create visually readable output. That may require removing whitespace as well as adding it. It's not a reasonable requirement to ask the serializer to create readable output and to preserve existing whitespace at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelKay the requirement was to add/remove prefixes given an xml. No other changes should be performed and the output would have to be the same. So if I get an xml which contains already prefixes and goes through the method to add them, it shouldn't modify the input, resulting in a perfect content match. As Input may contain some lines with and others without prefix, I cannot just rely on a basic check of the first line, the xlst has to do the full job

Comment: Then don't request indentation. Alternatively, do a logical comparison of the XML (e.g. by converting both files to canonical form) rather than a lexical comparison.

Comment: @MichaelKay the xlst is changing the indentation of the input xml. If you have an idea about how to do the prefix adjustment without modifying the rest of the output...

Comment: I think the serializer is changing the indentation, not the XSLT. Or it might be the XML parser - Microsoft parsers may strip whitespace from the input, depending on the exactly configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As for empty elements being serialized with e.g. `<foo />` instead of `<foo/>`, well, yes, that is the default empty element serialization the Microsoft's XML stack (XmlWriter) in .NET does, if you really want to enforce your own rules you would need to implement your own XmlWriter outputting the wanted format.

As for the indentation changing, I would start by not using `xsl:output indent="yes"` and of course also not an XmlWriter that enforces indentation. It might also be easier to control such issues if you let the XSLT processor transform to a file or stream instead of to an tree model like XDocument.

Answer (score 0):

First decide whether you want the XSLT processor to do the serialization, or the XmlWriter. Currently it's being done by the XmlWriter, so the XSLT serialization parameters are ignored.

Second, whichever one you choose, make sure indentation is switched off at that level.

Comment: I use the XSLT to add/remove prefixes according to the parameters I send. The XmlWriter is only used to add the tab based indendation.